# "managed_file" type element not showing in my custom block configure form

Tags: forms, media, files

I have been creating a portfolio section for my one page theme and I created a module for these section blocks. Now, I'm using the `hook_block_configure` to set the data into the blocks.

Only 1 "#managed_file" type element is showing, the other 5 is not. I think they are in the same structure since I just copy/paste and edit some variables.

Here is my code:

```
 case 'portfolio':
      // For portfolio #1
      //dpm($portfolio);
      $form['portfolio_text_1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Enter your text portfolio'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get($portfolio['text'][0],'Category 1'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
      );
      $form[$portfolio['image'][0]] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'image1',
        '#title' => t('Choose an Image File'),
        '#description' => t('Select an appropriate image for the above portfolio'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get($portfolio['image_fid'][0],''),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://files/images/',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
          'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        ),
      );

       // For portfolio #2
      $form['portfolio_text_2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Enter your text portfolio'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get($portfolio['text'][1],'Category 2'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
       );
      $form[$portfolio['image'][1]] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'image2',
        '#title' => t('Choose an Image File'),
        '#description' => t('Select an appropriate image for the above portfolio'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get($portfolio['image_fid'][1],''),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://files/images/',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
          'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        ),
      );

// more in here.. but since portfolio image 2 file uploader is not showing it is still the same as below.
```

My global variable:

```
  static $portfolio;

  $portfolio = array(
    'text' => array(
      'portfolio_text_1',
      'portfolio_text_2',
      'portfolio_text_3',
      'portfolio_text_4',
      'portfolio_text_5',
      'portfolio_text_6',
    ),
    'image_fid' => array(
      'portfolio_image_1_fid',
      'portfolio_image_2_fid',
      'portfolio_image_3_fid',
      'portfolio_image_4_fid',
      'portfolio_image_5_fid',
      'portfolio_image_6_fid',
    ),
    'image' => array(
      'portfolio_image_1',
      'portfolio_image_2',
      'portfolio_image_3',
      'portfolio_image_4',
      'portfolio_image_5',
      'portfolio_image_6',
    ),

  );
```

NOTE:

The textfields are showing, only the other 5 image uploader are not.

How to make it show up?

Thanks for your responses.